# Fail fo fetch observable changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular, reactivex

I have a `report.service.ts` that have one simple method to get `reports` (which is just a const array of reports object from a mock), and all it really does is this:

```
@Injectable()
export class ReportService {
  getReports() {
    var ret = Observable.create(function(observer){ observer.onComplete(REPORTS) });
    return ret;
  }
}
```

now in my `app.component` I want to get those reports. So I did:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'workPrioritizer-reports',
  styles: [require('./app.css')],
  template: require('./app.component.html'),
})

export class ReportsCmp implements OnInit{
  reports: Report[];
  title = 'Reorder List';

  constructor(private reportService: ReportService) {}

  getReports() {
    var sub = this.reportService.getReports().subscribe(function(x){return x});
    return sub;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getReports()
  }
}
```

this is it, but its not working, obviously im doing something wrong here, im new to observables :/

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in your `Observable.create` you need to use `observer.next(REPORTS)`.

also if you want to to invoke the complete function, you will have to change it to `observer.complete()`.